# groovy replaceAll strange behavior

Tags: groovy

I'm novice in Groovy. And I am confused a little.

Groovy code:

```
def str = 'D:\\bin'
def newStr = str.replaceAll(args[0],args[1])
println 'str    :' + str + ' (' + str.length() + ')'
println 'newStr :' + newStr + ' (' + newStr.length() + ')'
println 'args[0]:' + args[0] + ' (' + args[0].length() + ')'
println 'args[1]:' + args[1] + ' (' + args[1].length() + ')
assert str == args[0]
```

and now test it:

```
   >groovy test.groovy D:\bin C:\data 
   str    :D:\bin (6)
   newStr :D:\bin (6)
   args[0]:D:\bin (6)
   args[1]:C:\data (7)
```

replaceAll does nothing.
and another test:

```
  >groovy test.groovy D:\\bin C:\\data 
  str    :D:\bin (6)
  newStr :C:\data (7)
  args[0]:D:\\bin (7)
  args[1]:C:\\data (8)
  Caught: Assertion failed: 

  assert str == args[0]
         |   |  |   |
         |   |  |   D:\\bin
         |   |  [D:\\bin, C:\\data]
         |   false
         D:\bin
```

replaceAll works fine now, but we can see 'str' is not equals 'args[0]'
It seems to me GString and String are different.

The question is: why lengths are different ("D:\bin"- 6, "D:\\bin" - 7), but replacing is done.

Comment: It's nothing to do with `GString` (none of your strings above are `GString`s).  Try:  `'D:\\bin'.replaceAll('D:\\\\bin', 'C:\\data')`  It's an escaping issue

Comment: as you can see it is working. But strange behavior. Look at result newStr is 'C:\data' but args[1] was 'C:\\data'. Strings are different moreover lenghts are different.

Comment: Read the documentation on `String.replaceAll()`. It doesn't replace a strings with strings. It replaces *regular expressions* with strings. If you don't understand what a regular expression is, and how it is different than a string, then that is the place to start your inquiry.

Comment: You are right of course. It is my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [BalRog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142522/balrog). 'str' is a String, but 'args[0]' is a regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me GString and String are different.

This is true, but not relevant to your question because none of the strings in your code are GStrings.

The issue is that `\` is used to indicate special characters (tabs, spaces, etc.) in strings. If you want to use `\` to indicate a backslash character you either need to escape it with an extra backslash

```
def str = 'D:\\bin'
```

or alternatively, use [slashy strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string) instead

```
def str = /D:\bin/
```